# Importing a python script for a list of Items

Tags: python, python-import

I have a certain clustering code, which takes  variable named as market as parameter and does the processing. Now I want to run this code for all the markets through another script. Assuming my clustering script is Cmeans_omni and I am calling it from temp.py. So my piece of code is:

```
###temp.py
m= ['A','B','C', 'Other'] #market list
for market_for_clustering in m:
    import Cmeans_omni
```

Now problem comes that Cmeans_omni.py saves the output using the to_csv module. So the last line of the code is:

```
df.to_csv(output_dir + market +   output_filename,mode='w',index=False)   #df is the output data generated by C_means.py
```

The code would run for all the markets, but it would save the result in the output directory only for last market(parameter), which is Other. I want to save the results for all the markets. I know I am missing some very basic stuff, any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What sait said. Take a look at the section on [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) in the official Python tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You should change your structure a little bit:

**Cmeans_omni.py:**

```
def doWork(fileName):
   ...
   df.to_csv(fileName, mode='w', index=False)
```

**temp.py:**

```
import Cmeans_omni
markets = ['A.csv', 'B.csv', 'C.csv']
for m in markets:
   Cmeans_omni.doWork(m)
```